# "NA" in multiple regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I have a question about multiple regression

```
data$x4 <- with(data, x1+x2)   #x4=x1+x2
y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3
mod1 <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
```

I ran `summary(mod1)`, and the console showed up `NA` on estimate, std.error, t value, and Pr of x4.
I don't know why I can't obtain output about x4. please let me  know the reason why I can't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You have perfect [multicollinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multicollinearity/info).  That is, (at least) one of your regressor variables is a perfect linear combination of some (at least one) of your other regressor variables.  As a result, the design matrix is rank deficient, and the model cannot be estimated.  (Note that this is largely a logical constraint, not a software one.)  To deal with such cases, software will often 'throw out' offending variables.  In other words, it estimates the rest of the model by fitting a model without the collinear variables (that couldn't be estimated anyway).

In your case `x4` is collinear with `x1` and `x2` because it is a linear combination of them (specifically, `x4 = x1 + x2`).  So R estimated a model without `x4` and just wrote `NA` in that line of the output.

The way to 'fix' this is not to do it in the first place.

Comment: It's interesting to watch terminology change.  "Perfect multicollinearity" is what so far has more commonly been known as "collinearity" and "perfect linear combination" as a mere, pedestrian "linear combination" ;-).  Regardless, it's probably worth noting that there's more than one way to throw out "collinear variables" because collinearity is a *relationship* among variables: it doesn't mark any variable at all as specifically being "collinear." I believe `R` discards them in the order encountered in the model matrix.

Comment: @whuber, R is throwing out `x4` because it's last.  If the formula were `y~x2+x3+x4+x1`, then `x1` would be thrown out.  This is your "order encountered in the model matrix".  Regarding the terms, some have used "multicollinearity" to only mean *perfect linear combination*, etc, but over time people will refer to x1 & x2 as collinear when r(x1, x2)=.95, eg, even though they are not, strictly speaking, a linear combination, just highly correlated.  Because that is what "multicollinearity" has come to mean, I use "*perfect* multicollinearity" to refer to r=1.0.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I perfectly understood.

Comment: You're welcome, @terry. If this has resolved your question, you may want to *accept* it, by clicking the check mark below the vote total to its upper left, or *upvote* it, by clicking the upwards triangle over the vote total.

Comment: The reason to characterize the algorithm in terms of "order in the model matrix" is that one cannot determine the order merely by inspecting the formula except in the very simplest cases. When factor variables, interactions, and functions are involved, it can get complicated to determine the order. I doubt anyone ever used "multicollinear" as a synonym for collinear: the two meanings are (quite) different. Finally, although an absolute correlation coefficient of $1$ implies collinearity, in many cases collinearity occurs without any correlation coefficient being appreciably different from $0.$

Comment: @whuber, I used 2 variables for convenience / clarity. What I mean is, multicollinearity can be used to refer to a situation only when the matrix is rank deficient, or more loosely when it is almost-but-not-quite rank deficient. In the latter case, the model can still be fit, but be very unstable, with SE's so large as to be uninformative, etc. Many people will call that "multicollinear", even though it technically isn't.  Because the term has come to be used like that, & because that is reasonable in practical use, I use "*perfect* multicollinearity" to refer to situations w/ rank deficiency.

Comment: I believe your usage is a little out of the ordinary.  I have not encountered any textbook that uses this term *only* for rank deficient matrices.  One of the difficulties is that "multicollinear" is a vague concept: it covers everything that is not linearly independent and therefore comprises far more than rank deficiency.

Comment: @whuber, that's what I'm saying.  "Multicollinear" is used more broadly than just rank deficient matrices.  That's why I use "*perfect* multicollinearity" to refer to rank deficiency & "multicolliearity" to refer to situations that are 'close enough' to be problematic (which is how the term is used generally AFAICT, eg, for VIF>10).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I interpreted your earlier "multicollinearity can be used to refer to a situation only when the matrix is rank deficient" to mean the opposite of that.  The "only" confused me.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like "only" may have been poorly / ambiguously placed.